# "NoSuchMethodError: The getter element..." while generating with retrofit_generator

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit

**Flutter 1.17.3**

```yaml
retrofit_generator: ^1.3.7
```

I run this command

```sh
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

and the following error was received during generation

```
[SEVERE] retrofit_generator:retrofit on lib/data_services/calendar/repository/calendar_network_repository.dart:
Error running RetrofitGenerator
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'element' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: element
```

Class's code where error happens

```dart
part 'calendar_network_repository.g.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: Url.profiles)
abstract class CalendarNetworkRepository {
  factory CalendarNetworkRepository(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _CalendarNetworkRepository;

  @GET('/{userId}/diary')
  Future<List<dynamic>> getData(
      @Path('userId') int userId, @Query('start') String startDate, @Query('end') String endDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**

**Don't** use `dynamic` in signatures for methods which will be generated by retrofit_generator

---

Generation fails due to the fact `dynamic` has been used

```dart
Future<List<dynamic>> getData
```

This error happens in source_gen's [type_checker](https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen/blob/master/source_gen/lib/src/type_checker.dart#L170)

```dart
bool isExactlyType(DartType staticType) => isExactly(staticType.element);
```

because as we know `staticType == null`. Now lets find out why it is null.
for return type like `Future<List<SomeType>>` retrofit_generator must generate [code for transformation](https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/blob/master/generator/lib/src/generator.dart#L423) Map to SomeType instance

```dart
blocks.add(Code("var value = $_resultVar.data.map((dynamic i) => $innerReturnType.fromJson(i as Map<String,dynamic>)).toList();"));
```

Lets see how `innerReturnType` has been declared

```dart
final innerReturnType = _getResponseInnerType(returnType);
```

In we see [check for dynamic](https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/blob/master/generator/lib/src/generator.dart#L225)

```
if (generic.isDynamic) return null;
```

After this `isExactlyType` was called and we get error